# How to migrate datetime to datetime2 with new SQL Server Native Client

Tags: c++, sql-server, oledb, datetime2, sql-server-native-client

We are currently migrating our database from `datetime`to `datetime2` including SQL Server Native Client v11 (SQL Server 2012). The database update was easily done, but the problems come along with the new SQL Server Native Client 11 we want to use.

In general we have OLE DB Consumers with "COLUMN_ENTRY*" accessors for our CRUD operations in place. For the `datetime2` columns the members have the type `DBTIMESTAMP`. With the `SQLNCLI` provider the fraction part of the `DBTIMESTAMP` was silently truncated to the supported value. With the `SQLNCLI11` an insert with too precise fraction results in this error:

`DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.`

According to [this link](http://www.adopenstatic.com/faq/80040e21.asp), this error is returned if too much data is being inserted into a field. From this I assumed that the fractional part of the DBDATETIME member is too precise to be inserted. According to [this link](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/330168/command-execute-using-sqlncli10-ole-db-with-parameter-binding-fails-if-datetime-fraction-0), the new Native Client Versions (10 and 11) do not truncate but fail in an error. Take this simplified example what we want to achieve:

```cpp
class CMyTableStruct
{
public: 
    CMyTableStruct();
    LONG m_lID;
    DBTIMESTAMP m_dtLogTime;
};
class CMyTableStruct_InsertAccessor : public CMyTableStruct
{
public:
    BEGIN_PARAM_MAP(CMyTableStruct_InsertAccessor)
        COLUMN_ENTRY(1,  m_dtLogTime)
    END_PARAM_MAP()  
};
```

At some part in the code I initialize the timestamp to 2015-08-10 07:47:49.986149999 and the insert fails. If I reset the fraction to 0, the insert works; any value beside 0 fails. I tried to supply the datetime precision and scale using `COLUMN_ENTRY_PS` with various values, but the inserts always failed.

How can we force the Native Client to simply accept the value and truncate it? It's quite obvious that we cannot truncate all the values manually to the supported DB precision. I couldn't find any proper documentation about how to use datetime2 with the new Native Client. Are we missing any conversion or setting to handle datetime2 correctly?

This is the test setup:

- Windows 7 64bit
- SQL Server Native Client 11 (SQLNCLI11)
- SQL Server 2012
- DBPROP_INIT_LCID=2055
- DBPROP_INIT_PROMPT=4
- DBPROP_INIT_DATASOURCE=localhost
- DBPROP_AUTH_INTEGRATED=SSPI

With the `SQLNCLI` provider the same code works.

[EDIT#1]: I dumped some more error information using `AtlTraceErrorRecords` and this confirmed the same error as in the linked Microsoft Connect report:

`Row #:    0 Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Description: "The fractional part of the provided time value overflows the scale of the corresponding SQL Server parameter or column. Increase bScale in DBPARAMBINDINFO or column scale to correct this error." Help File: "(null)" Help Context:    0 GUID: {0C733A63-2A1C-11CE-ADE5-00AA0044773D}`

[EDIT#2]: From my further research it looks like this is the defined and accepted behavior of the new Native Client. See [Stricter SQL_C_TYPE _TIMESTAMP and DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP parameter validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964722(v=sql.110).aspx) for reference. But Microsoft can't take this change serious without any documentation how to properly use datetime2 then. Do they really require the developers themselves to round the DBTIMESTAMP before inserting them into the database? In some cases rounding even does not work because of some floating point precision errors. Take the example timestamp from above and you'll see the typical .9999 precision error. How is anybody supposed to get this strange behavior working? With this error messages you can't even save a current timestamp to the database without using the SQL function for `now()` because you'll usually run in those overflows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did few tests and completely rewrote my answer.

I use SQL Server 2008 with Native Client 10. It already supports `datetime2(7)`, so my tests are applicable.

**datetime**

I have a stored procedure that has a table-valued parameter. One of the columns of the parameter's table has `datetime` type. I wasn't using non-zero fractions of a second before, but tried now. It took me a while to figure out what is needed.

In order to use non-zero value in the `DBTIMESTAMP.fraction` field I had to configure both column description and parameter description: set `DBCOLUMNDESC.bScale` to 3 and `DBBINDING.bScale` to 3. Both `bPrecision` was left at 0. This [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677303.aspx) helped me to realise that I have to set `DBCOLUMNDESC.bScale` as well.

> The SQL Server Native Client OLE DB provider inspects the DBCOLUMDESC
>   *bScale* member to determine the fractional seconds precision.

Once `Scale` is set to 3 I could set the value of `DBTIMESTAMP.fraction` to `555000000` and it was inserted successfully into the database as `.557`, i.e. the server rounded the value further to 1/3 of the millisecond (precision of the `datetime` type). **But**, when I tried to set the value of `DBTIMESTAMP.fraction` to `552100000`, I got the same error as you are getting. So, the server expects the programmers to round the values themselves.

One simple way to truncate fractions would be something like this:

```
DBTIMESTAMP dt;
// set to any value from 0 to 999,999,999 (billionth of a second)
dt.fraction = 555123456; 

// truncate fractions to milliseconds before inserting into the database
dt.fraction /= 1000000;
dt.fraction *= 1000000;
```

**datetime2(7)**

I changed the type of the column in the table-valued parameter to `datetime2(7)` and did few more tests.

I set `Scale` to 7 and could successfully insert into the database `DBTIMESTAMP.fraction` with the value `555123400`, but when I tried to insert value `555123478` I got the same error. So, for `datetime2(7)` server also expects programmers to round the values themselves.

```
// truncate fractions to 100 nanoseconds precision
dt.fraction /= 100;
dt.fraction *= 100;
```

Should be enough.

Comment: Yes I get the same error if I set the precision to 7. I tried to use ridiculous high values (>50) to make the Native Client accept any huge value, but also those inserts fail. The Native Client fails to convert such detailed fractions to the datetime2(7) without truncation which leads to this error. Regarding the manual truncation you're right, it should be theoretically possible to do it. But it is almost impossible to change and maintain all places in code in order to truncate the fraction after setting a timestamp. Is there maybe a way to do this automatically on oledb/ATL level?

Comment: Well, if I understood correctly this [Connect article](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/330168/command-execute-using-sqlncli10-ole-db-with-parameter-binding-fails-if-datetime-fraction-0), MS says that fraction should be divisible by `1,000,000` for `datetime`. So, for `datetime2(7)` it should be divisible by `100`. I would introduce this kind of rounding/truncation in corresponding getters or setters of your class. `ULONG fraction = fraction / 100 * 100`

Comment: Based on the links that you included in the question, it seems that yes, they do really require now the developers themselves to round the fraction part of `DBTIMESTAMP` before inserting it into the database. Whether it is 3, 7, or any other precision. And also, you have to specify your chosen precision in `Precision` and `Scale` fields of `DBPARAMBINDINFO`.

Comment: I found out that we have some nice application time to DBTIMESTAMP conversions in place (even if they are not used everywhere). I'll do some tests how the inserting behaves when I add some rounding (clearing the lowest 2-3 digits to 0) and will update you how it behaves.

Comment: I did few tests and completely rewrote my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the great response. I also just finished my tests and I was able to rework the areas where we map our internal date classes to the DBTIMESTAMP. As you suggested I truncate the fraction using the division. It works but I really wonder what Microsoft was thinking here. At least an additional setting for the connection would have been nice to disable those errors.

Comment: No problem. I tried to use fractional seconds a while ago, but failed and never got back to it until you asked this question and I was interested to solve it. Now I finally figured out what I was missing (setting `Scale` in two places). [MS says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964722%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) that they now follow OLE DB requirements and prevent **silent** data loss. By shifting responsibility to the caller to truncate/round the data to the needed precision as the caller needs. Not convenient, but sort of makes sense. Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

When using C# or VB with the OleDb library, set the OleDbParameter.Scale value to avoid this error message.

Tested with Provider=SQLNCLI11.